# Почему произошло такое при git push?

Tags: git

Я работал в ветке `feature-a`, в которой было сделано несколько комитов (еще не пушил), также были измененные файлы, которые еще не добавил через `git add`.
В этот момент у меня появилась необходимость, пофиксить в 1 фале баг.
Для этого я сделал следующее:

`git checkout -b bugfix/bug-branch-name`

внес изменения в файл (исправил баг)

```
git add filename
git commit -m "comment"
git push origin HEAD
```

далее иду на github, чтобы сделать pull-request и сделать merge с мастером.
Сделал pull-request и вижу, что почему-то у меня 3 комита.. 
почему в эту ветку попали еще 2 комита с ветки, в которой я работал ранее (до того, как переключился на ветку bugfix) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы отвели свою ветку от своих текущих коммитов.

```
C3 (HEAD, bugfix/bug-branch-name)
C2 (master)
C1
C0 (origin/master)
```

Надо было сделать

```
git checkout -b bugfix/bug-branch-name origin/master
```

тогда ветка отвелась бы от мастера-на-сервере.

```
C3 (HEAD, bugfix/bug-branch-name)
|
|  C2 (master)
|  C1
| /
C0 (origin/master)
```

Посмотрите граф своих веток:

```
$ git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all -10
```

Comment: эхх... спасибо большое!

а я думал, когда пишу git push .. то отправляются все коммиты только текущей ветки. я же в новой ветке делал только 1 комит..

а можно было вместо `git push origin HEAD`, написать `git push origin #код комита# ` ? - тогда бы только 1 комит попал ? или такая запись некорректна?


И еще теперь непонятно как распутать получившийся результат. Теперь в github у меня pull-request висит, с веткой bugfix в который попали важные feature-комиты.. Можно ли вернуть обратно пулреквест и разделить комиты по разным веткам ?

Comment: @23423423 Вы отметили ответ как принятый, значит ваша проблема в этой теме решена. Если у вас остались вопросы, то задайте пожалуйста новый вопрос и сошлитесь на текущий как на взаимосвязанный. Не стоит этого делать в комментарии.

Comment: @23423423 прочитайте ответ ещё раз, и внимательнее. Все 3 коммита находятся в вашей ветке.